# NuGet restore package with xml file content - Working sample?

Tags: xml, visual-studio-2015, package, nuget, restore

Tools Used: Visual Studio 2015 Enterprise, Nuget 3.5, .NET Framework 4.0

Does anyone have a working sample of a NuGet Package that includes some xml files as well as dll libraries?

I have read scattered notes about this in many places, but I have yet to find a working sample.  There seems to be debate as to whether xml files belong in net folder or in content files folder.  I am also reading that we require some sort of power shell script to copy the file into bin when the package installs?

The xml has to be in the BIN folder with the dlls when the package installs.

A working sample would help a lot.

Answer (score 0):

> The xml has to be in the BIN folder with the dlls when the package installs.

If you want distribute your xml files with your NuGet package in the same folder as your dlls, you will need to add them to your .nuspec file, for example:

```
<files>
<file src="bin\Debug\TestNuGetPackage.dll" target="lib\Net462" />
<file src="bin\Debug\TestNuGetPackage.xml" target="lib\Net462" />
</files>
```

Below are the detail steps:

1. Create a blank C# Class Library project, open the project in the File Explorer.
2. Use `nuget spec "..\TestNuGetPackage.csproj"` to create `TestNuGetPackage.csproj.nuspec` file.
3. Modify the .nuspec file, below is my .nuspec file:

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0"?>
   <package >
    <metadata>
      <id>TestNuGetPackage</id>
      <version>1.0.0</version>
      <authors>Tester</authors>
      <owners>Tester</owners>
      <requireLicenseAcceptance>false</requireLicenseAcceptance>
      <description>A description of your library</description>
      <releaseNotes>Release notes for this versio</releaseNotes>
      <copyright>Copyright 2017</copyright>
      <tags>Tag1 Tag2</tags>
    </metadata>
   <files>
     <file src="bin\Debug\TestNuGetPackage.dll" target="lib\Net462" />
     <file src="bin\Debug\TestNuGetPackage.xml" target="lib\Net462" />
   </files>
   </package>
   ```
4. Use `nuget.exe pack "..\TestNuGetPackage.csproj.nuspec"` to create a package.
5. Create a test project with .net framework 4.62, then install that package to the project and build it, you will find the xml file has to be in the BIN folder with the dlls.

Comment: I can get the xml to show up in the Net40 folder I am  using in the nuget package.  The problem is the xml does not restore to the bin folder when the dll does.  The xml does not restore at all.  Maybe there is a switch I need to add to my nuget restore to get the xml to restore as well?  I thought I was buliding the packages wrong, but it looks like I am doing those right.

Comment: I have figured out what the problem is: Project.Json and .NET Framework 4.0.  If I use 452 and package.config file all works fine, but if you use the tools I specified above this does NOT work, sorry.

Comment: Wow, you are right. I have not noticed it before, thanks for you sharing. This may not support in the previous version framework and project.json. You can convert your comment to answer, then mark it, so it could help other community members who get the same issues and easier to find the reason for this issue. Thanks.

Comment: Well, there is no solution, I don't know if I want to mark this as answered.  This appears to be an actual MS defect in the software.  It does not make any sense to only support dll files in nuget packages at Nuget 3.5.  There is no documentation that suggests xml is excluded either.  All the documentation suggests xml is indeed supported.

Comment: I have been able to get this to work with the ContentFiles folder, BUT not with NPM and VS 2015.  It only works with nuget.exe 3.5 directly.  So if you want to restore your xml files, you have to go out of VS 2015 and restore from the command line to get your xml files restored correctly.